# What's the right way to do exception handling in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Assume that I have the base controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

Also, I have some inherited controllers, like:

```
class JobController < ApplicationController
```

I'd like to explicitly handle some sub-set of exceptions in `JobController` while in the `ApplicationController`, I'll handle all the remaining ones.

What's the right way to do exception handling in Ruby on Rails? I know that we can use: `rescue_from` and `around_action`. So which is the preferred way?

Comment: Here's a great article about error handling in Rails: [modular error handling](https://medium.com/rails-ember-beyond/error-handling-in-rails-the-modular-way-9afcddd2fe1b)

Answer (score 0):

i think adding rescue_from to application_controller is a good way to handling exceptions.

for example (rails 5.*):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ::ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    render plain: exception.message, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

after that in all actions you will get:

```
["Couldn't find * with 'id'=1"]
```